# Express 4.0 (Node:IOjs) how can I use sockets inside of express.Router()?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I did some googling about using routes and sockets together. Basically I have my routes exported in different files basic out line like

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get(function(req, res){})

module.exports = router;
```

Basically inside a .get function I have a few different callbacks that happen and I would like to emit to a socket on the front end every time it progresses to the next callback almost like a progress e.g.

"Partitioning Data"
"Creating Server"

Then if needed
"Failed to create server"

If I wasn't clear just ask I'm expecting something like

```
router.get(function(req, res){
   req.io.to(socketid).emit('update', 'Making Server');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation is an example that the server fetches data from twitter and emit events to the client side.  The client renders the emitted event and renders the page accordingly.

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});

// Initialize socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.emit('tweet', 'using sockets now...');
```

And the client side does something like this.

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    socket.on('tweet', function (data) {
        // getting tweets here
    });
</script>
```

Not sure if there's something like req.io but I guess you can setup middlewares and make it what you want.

https://github.com/scotch-io/react-tweets/tree/master/views

Comment: I don't see how this solves the particular problem the question asks.